# django+docker to elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created a super simple django app in docker, following these instructions: https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

Everything works locally. 
When I try to upload the folder that includes `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` to AWS Elastic Beanstalk as a multicontainer docker, it does not work. Should I also provide `Dockerrun.aws.json`?

here is what I have in `Dockerfile`:

```
   FROM python:3
   ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
   RUN mkdir /code
   WORKDIR /code
   ADD requirements.txt /code/
   RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
   ADD . /code/
```

and in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  version: '3'

  services:
    db:
      image: postgres
    web:
      build: .
      command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
      volumes:
        - .:/code
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      depends_on:
        - db
```

Comment: by 'uploading the folder' I mean zipping and uploading an archive to Elastic Beanstalk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to provide a `Dockerrun` file. From [the official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html#create_deploy_docker_ecs_dockerrun):

> Multicontainer Docker instances on Elastic Beanstalk require a
>   configuration file named `Dockerrun.aws.json`. This file is specific
>   to Elastic Beanstalk and can be used alone or combined with source
>   code and content in a [source bundle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html) to create an environment on a
>   Docker platform.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, but what should I write there? are there any 'standard' settings for a typical django app?

Comment: I've found a very minimalistic version of Dockerrun.aws.json:
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Logging": "/var/eb_log"
}
here: https://github.com/glynjackson/django-docker-template/blob/master/Dockerrun.aws.json
Is that enough?

Comment: Please read the link to docs given above. They provide info on how to write a dockerrun file: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun